# Python: Take URL as an argument

Tags: python, regex, arguments

I have made this script that currently works as I want it to. The URL (visible at the bottom of the script) is obviously hard coded into the script. I want the script to prompt the user for the URL or have the script be run with an argument of the URL to be fetched. I'm new to python and have no idea, any help would be appreciated!

```
import sys, re 
import webpage_get

def print_links(page): 
 ''' find all hyperlinks on a webpage passed in as input and 
print ''' 
 print '[*] print_links()' 
 # regex to match on hyperlinks, returning 3 grps, links[1] being the link itself 
 links = re.findall(r'\http\://\www.+', page)
 # sort and print the links 
 links.sort() 
 print '[+]', str(len(links)), 'HyperLinks Found:' 
 for link in links: 
     print link
def get_email(str):

    print '[*] get_email()'
    emails = re.findall(r'\w+\@\w+.com', str)
    email.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(emails)), 'Emails Found:'
    for mail in emails:
        print mail
def get_numbers(page):
    print '[*] get_numbers()'
    numbers = re.findall ('[44\d\s]{11}', page)
    numbers.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(numbers)), 'Numbers Found'
    for no in numbers:
        print no
def main(): 
 # temp testing url argument 
 sys.argv.append('http://URLGOESHERE.com') 

 # Check args 
 if len(sys.argv) != 2: 
     print '[-] Usage: webpage_getlinks URL' 
     return 

 # Get the web page 
 page = webpage_get.wget(sys.argv[1]) 
 # Get the links 
 print_links(page)
 get_numbers(page)

 #get_email(str)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
     main()
```

Comment: Isnt't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338000/taking-an-argument-from-user-url ?

Answer (score 3):

> I want the script to prompt the user for the URL or have the script be run with an argument of the URL to be fetched

For the first, do this:

```
url = raw_input('URL: ')
```

For the second, do this:

```
url = sys.argv[1]
```

So, if you want to use the arg if it's there, ask otherwise, do this:

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    url = raw_input('URL: ')
else:
    url = sys.argv[1]
```

---

If you want to get any fancier than just taking a single optional argument, consider using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

And

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

And

http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

You can use ArgumentParser to define your command line args, check the and prompt the user if URL isn't there and validate the user input via urlparse